# Tomorrows date with leading zeros?

Tags: date, batch-file

I'm looking to have a method of printing tomorrows date in a DD/MM/YYYY format. I'm currently running the following set of cmds:

```
@echo off

set /a d=%date:~0,2%
set /a m=%date:~3,2%
set /a y=%date:~6,4%


:loop
   set /a d+=1

   if %d% gtr 31 (
      set d=1
      set /a m+=1

      if %m% gtr 12 (
         set m=1
         set /a y+=1
      )
   )

xcopy /d:%m%-%d%-%y% /h /l "%~f0" "%~f0\" >nul 2>&1 || goto loop
echo The date tomorrow is "%d%/%m%/%y%".

pause
```

The above works nicely, printing "The date tomorrow is "8/12/2012". However, I need both my DAY and MONTH values to come out with leading zeros when less than 10. I can't appear to figure out how this can be done. Could anyone help me?

Cheers,

EL

Answer (score 1):

Your grabbing the wrong information for the sets for day/month/year.
Here are the correct sets

```
set /a d=%date:~7,2%
set /a m=%date:~4,2%
set /a y=%date:~10,4%
```

Comment: This might depend on the locale.

Comment: I guess that is true, it seems like he's british or european based on how he sets up his days/months/years unlike the american system months/days/years. Good call

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to easily figure out what variables go where by the following:

```
@echo off

:testing
set /a a=%date:~0,1%
set /a b=%date:~1,1%
set /a c=%date:~2,1%
set /a d=%date:~3,1%
set /a e=%date:~4,1%
set /a f=%date:~5,1%
set /a g=%date:~6,1%
set /a h=date:~7,1%
set /a i=%date:~8,1%
set /a j=%date:~9,1%
set /a k=%date:~10,1%
set /a l=%date:~11,1%
set /a m=%date:~12,1%
set /a n=%date:~13,1%

echo.%a%-a
echo.%b%-b
echo.%c%-c
echo.%d%-d
echo.%e%-e
echo.%f%-f
echo.%g%-g
echo.%h%-h
echo.%i%-i
echo.%j%-j
echo.%k%-k
echo.%l%-l
echo.%m%-m
echo.%n%-n
```

then when you get the first value you want it will be

```
set /a var=%date:~NUM1,NUM2%
```

Where NUM1 is the start NUM2 is how many characters to move to the right and VAR is the variable you want to set it to.

Alternatively using FOR statements might work better.

I saw that someone had mentioned that the user might be from EU or British. If that is the case their date setup would be (using FOR):

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
set day=%dd%
set /a day+=01
SET date=%day%/%mm%/%yyyy%
echo.%date%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Opps. I think I've just fixed my own problem by adding:

```
IF 1%d% LSS 100 SET d=0%d%
IF 1%m% LSS 100 SET m=0%m%
```

Before xcopy. So it should now read:

```
@echo off

set /a d=%date:~0,2%
set /a m=%date:~3,2%
set /a y=%date:~6,4%

:loop
   set /a d+=1

   if %d% gtr 31 (
      set d=1
      set /a m+=1

      if %m% gtr 12 (
         set m=1
         set /a y+=1
      )
   )

IF 1%d% LSS 100 SET d=0%d%
IF 1%m% LSS 100 SET m=0%m%
xcopy /d:%m%-%d%-%y% /h /l "%~f0" "%~f0\" >nul 2>&1 || goto loop
echo The date tomorrow is "%d%/%m%/%y%".

pause
```

Hope that helps anyone with a similar issue :)

Comment: I believe you have fooled yourself. Months can have 28,29,30, or 31 days. Your code assumes all months have 31 days. One good solution is to convert date to Julian date, add 1, then convert back to Gregorian date. See [DosTips :date2jdate, :jdate, and :jdate2date functions](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsDateTime.php#Function.date2jdate).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code... it did not work
Here is a proper portion of batch code that will work for what you need.

```
:getdate
set /a day=%date:~7,2%
IF %day% LSS 10 set day=0%day%
rem echo.The day is - %day%

set /a month=%date:~4,2%
IF %month% LSS 10 set month=0%month%
rem echo.The month is - %month%

set /a year=%date:~10,4%
rem echo.The year is - %year%

REM Setting Month / Days
set jan=31
set feb=28
set mar=31
set apr=30
set may=31
set jun=30
set jul=31
set aug=31
set sep=30
set oct=31
set nov=30
set dec=31

REM If Months are # set Month to Days
IF %month% EQU 1 set mon=%jan%
IF %month% EQU 2 set mon=%feb%
IF %month% EQU 3 set mon=%mar%
IF %month% EQU 4 set mon=%apr%
IF %month% EQU 5 set mon=%may%
IF %month% EQU 6 set mon=%jun%
IF %month% EQU 7 set mon=%jul%
IF %month% EQU 8 set mon=%aug%
IF %month% EQU 9 set mon=%sep%
IF %month% EQU 10 set mon=%oct%
IF %month% EQU 11 set mon=%nov%
IF %month% EQU 12 set mon=%dec%

echo.Today's Date is %month%/%day%/%year%

set /a day+=1
if %day% GTR %mon% set /a month+=1
if %day% GTR %mon% set day=1
IF %day% LSS 10 set day=0%day%
IF %month% GTR 12 set month=1& set /a year+=1
IF %month% LSS 10 set month=0%month%

echo.Tomorrow's Date is %month%/%day%/%year%
```

This will set the days in a month (except leap years) and should solve any problems you have, assuming you don't know this yet, but if a month only has 30 days your current code will set the day to 31, regardless if it's say Feburary and there are only 28 days.

You will have to insert your other code into here, as I'm not sure what your loop is doing, otherwise I just changed the d = day, m = month and y = year (mon is comparing the days in the month).

Good luck, HTH